# Whitney-Mann and multiple regression

Tags: regression, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Is it appropriate to use Whitney-Mann (to compare the groups) and multiple Regression model  (to analyse each factor) within the same data? (parametric and non-parametric test on the same data)